# Improper Integration Gamma function

Tags: calculus

How to compute the following integral $$\int_y^\infty \frac{3}{x}e^{-3x}dx$$ I tried to use integration by parts or use Gamma function. However, it does not work. Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that substituting $u=3x$ gives us $$I = \int_{y}^{\infty} \frac{3}{x}e^{-3x} dx = \int_{3y}^{\infty} (-3)\frac{-e^{-u}}{u} du = -3E_1(3x)$$ where $E_1(x)$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Solving gives $I = 3\Gamma(0,3y)$ where $\Gamma(s,x)$ is the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Comment: Aren't you missing a term ? It seems to me that $I=3 (\log (y)+\Gamma (0,3 y))$